# What does "factor of true classifications" mean?

Tags: r

I am trying to use `knn` in R, and in the documentation page [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html), it says that the parameter `cl` is "factor of true classifications of training set".

The actual parameter passed into the example is a vector of 25 `s`'s, 25 `c`'s, and 25 `v`'s.

I have looked at the R manual page for `factor`, but that did not help me understand the purpose and usage of the parameter `cl`. Can anyone give a hint for what it means and how it is used?

Comment: It looks like `knn` is from the `class` package, which is associated with a textbook, linked in the documentation (under "URL"): http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/class/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a method of setting prior probabilities when such are available to the analyst. The sampling process may not always result in a set of values that are close to the true proportions. The `factor` function is the R method of converting items to discrete or categorical values. Regression and classification functions may expect such values.